# ArcGIS Server Data Extraction - Job does not exist or is inaccessible

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing

I have followed the documentation and [video](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/video/arcgis-server/details?entryID=4A08A4AE-1422-2418-888D-E79B9C266306) to set up a data extraction geoprocessing service, which I am accessing with the ArcGIS Viewer for Flex (v. 2.3.1).  When I run the Extract Data widget in the viewer I get an error: Job '(job folder name)' does not exist or is inaccessible.  When I go to the arcgisjobs folder on the server the folder is there, along with the scratch folder and the output .zip file containing the data that was clipped.  According to the messages.xml file in the scratch folder, the job finishes successfully.

I have checked the ArcGIS Server and Windows logs and haven't found anything obvious that would point to an issue.  Folder permissions should be correct, since the task can create the job folder, clip the data, and create the output .zip folder.  The task will run successfully when used through ArcGIS Desktop.

So has anyone experienced similar behavior with the data extraction tool or any other GP tasks?  Any ideas of where I can look next?

Environment:
ArcGIS Server 10, .NET, SP2 - Distributed installation
ArcGIS Desktop 10, SP2
Windows Server 2008 x64 R2
Thanks,
Tim

**Update:**
I did some testing today (in Firefox) and found a few more things:
 1.  The GP Service does *occasionally* work, it seems.  Every few tries I do get a prompt to download the extracted data, only to get a security sandbox violation:
http://**SERVER IP**/Samples/DataExtract/Flex/widgets/DataExtract/DataExtractWidget.swf cannot load data from http://**SERVER NAME**/arcgisjobs/sumner.dataextract_gpserver/j77643b1b114e458f82e6f416262aaf58/scratch/output.zip.
 2.  When I am prompted to download the file, Firebug shows that it cannot download my crossdomain.xml file.  It shows the address as http://**SERVER NAME**/crossdomain.xml

In both cases, it is trying to access a http://servername URL, and can't get there.  Problem is, I can't figure out where it's getting this URL.  I tried modifying the virtual directory URL's and republishing the services using the ArcGIS Server IP instead of machine name, with no change in behavior.

Comment: When you run [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), does it show any errors?

Comment: @Kirk, after I hit the Extract button I get two HTTP 200's.  Looking at the TextView, the first says the job is submitted, the second has the error about the directory being inaccessible.

Comment: What url is it trying to access in the second call?

Comment: The second call is to:
GET /ArcGIS/rest/services/Wilson.DataExtract/GPServer/WilsonExtract/jobs/jca7dd1279b3140b6896d6867bda55037?%5Fts=1306328682903&f=json

Comment: Just wondering if you had any definite solution to this error you were getting. I am experiencing it to and it is driving my crazy trying to work out why it works some times but not others. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Louise - I eventually moved on as we went another route with our data extraction jobs.  I think my issue was ultimately related to access to the arcgisoutput folder.  It sounds like you get an output .pdf sometimes - I wasn't getting anything.

Answer (score 1):

If its the script I'm thinking of, the jobs directory is hardcoded in the script.
Crack open the script and make sure the jobs directory in the script lines up with what you have in your environment.

From what you've said, it sounds like the job is completing successfully, it just is returning the wrong URL to the FlexApp to download the .zip file.

Comment: @KHimba, I'm not very python-savvy, but I'll open up the script tomorrow.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Tim, the video works for me this morning (didnt yesterday)- I was mistaken in what script I thought it was. You shouldnt have to edit anything in the script - follow Kirk's suggestions on looking at where the output is being written to / being sure your virtual directories are set correctly. Can you start another GP Service and have it work?

Comment: @KHimba That's what I thought, that it should "just work."  I think the settings in the virtual directories are good, since the GP Service is able to get there to write the files.  I may try to start another data extract GP service to see if the results are any different.

Comment: I started another GP service with new data, new .mxd, etc., and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a AGS10 SP2 distributed setup that seems similar to yours. I've been developing a PDF service based on [ArcPy.Mapping Simple ExportToPDF Geoprocessing Service Example](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=442e1c7ff64240af8f41825f567e60d0) and am encountering the same "Job xx does not exist or is inaccessible" message you are.

In my case, it seems to be an issue of timing: the task completes but the process tries to access the results before they can be moved from the SOC to the SOM's jobs folder.

A temporary workaround is to intercept the specific error, extract the JobID, and make a call to retrieve the generated PDF:

```
function gpError(e) {
    if (e.message.search("does not exist or is inaccessible") > -1) {
        var jobId = e.message.replace(/Job '([a-z,0-9]*)' does not exist or is inaccessible\./, "$1");
        gp.getResultData(jobId, "Output_PDF");
    }
    else {
        showDialog(dojo.string.substitute('<h1>Error: ${error}</h1>', { error: e.message }));
    }
}
```

This is definitely not something I would put into production but it does allow me to workaround the error and continue development work while I wait for ESRI to solve the problem.

Comment: Nice.  I'm using the Flex viewer so I don't think I can use this exactly, but it's an interesting work around.  I'll be opening a case with ESRI as well to get this sorted out.